# Show a custom field in a block

Tags: 7, theming, entities, blocks

I 'm getting crazy trying to show a value of a custom field (now in core) in a sidebar block. I have tried to show it with the render function, calling directly the field, with no luck.

I have a custom content type named "content1" and a  custom field named "field_test1"; I want that value to be shown on a block that will be visible while viewing the page node.

Do you have any suggestion on how to do it?

Comment: [This answer suggests different options](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6930/splitting-up-content-fields-into-different-regions/6935#6935). I'm sure one of them will suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the following code, to render a field.

```
render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_test1'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way would be to create a view, that will output the field you want.
And you can create a block out of that view.

If you are new to views, heres a video tutorial on how to do it:

http://learnbythedrop.com/drop/139

With views you can do pretty much without coding.

Answer (score 0):

In your [`hook_block_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--block--block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7) implementation, retrieve the current node with [`menu_get_object()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7), get the field values using [`field_get_items()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.module/function/field_get_items/7) and render the first one with [`field_view_value()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.module/function/field_view_value/7).

```
$node = menu_get_object('node');
if ($node && $node->type === 'content1') {
  $items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_test1');
  if ($items) {
    $rendered_field_value = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_test1', $items[0]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the job of http://drupal.org/project/cck_blocks

when adding a filed you will need to click on available as block.

you may want to hide the display of field from manage display.

Field is available as a block, goto block administration page and place your block in your required region