# How to show fields in different regions?

Tags: entities, theming

I've tried the `Display Suite module`, which only comes with regions per display suite layout template (also the extra module did not change this) which basically just changes the body/ content region... making the themes regions available was not possible. It still would be a bit overkill for what I want anyways.

All I want to do is make a field from within any content type available to be put in any region. No blocks. No views.

Just as the `display suite module` offers a new column in the `manage display tab` "region" with a drop down to pick which region the field shall be put in.

How come there is no module like that?

Thanks!

Edit: I've read [this thread](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6930/splitting-up-content-fields-into-different-regions?rq=1) but I want to do it without views and if possible without blocks.

Comment: last thing left is panels - http://drupal.org/project/panels - then. But it won't use regions like you would think.

Comment: so then panels isnt the thing aswell. really sad :(

Comment: correct me if I am wrong but: regions technically only contain blocks, views generate block displays for being placed inside there too. So there isnt a way to do that without "blocks". You could use context to place a block of your node display in the left block and render it for a specfic display though.

Comment: you are perfectly right but views does a whole lot of additional stuff for just displaying a simple field as a block (for instance going through the database again although the field's data has already been loaded when viewing the node). I've now done it with "Field as Block" module, which works pretty nicely but maybe there is still a better solution for this. Thank you :)

Comment: It really should be possible with Display Suite Extras: https://swsblog.stanford.edu/blog/using-display-suite-place-node-fields-blocks

Comment: I also wonder if Views is indeed such a bad option. It uses indeed extra database power, but also Views can be cached. For an anonymous user, the delay would be zero...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with anything in Drupal there are many ways of doing this. Display suite and Panels (as mentioned by Serpiente above) are great. However, if you are not already using them for your project, they are indeed overkill to get what you need.

You can use the [CCK Blocks](http://drupal.org/project/cck_blocks) or [Field as Block](http://drupal.org/project/fieldblock) module. These essentially turn any field (you set) into a block to be placed in another region.

You can also use the Views module to create a block with a contextual filter based on the nid in the url and display whatever fields you choose.

Comment: He said without blocks if possible...

Comment: Other than what I have mentioned above I don't think there is any other way.

Comment: what about panels?

Comment: does panels let you assign fields to different regions? i am afraid they dont

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve this with Display Suite by converting field into a block which you can then place in other regions using the block admin page. Information on how to do this can be found in the [Add fields to a block](https://drupal.org/node/1795354) page of the Display Suite documentation

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to avoid using blocks at all cost, you could print separate fields using the theme. For example, in page.tpl.php or node.tpl.php you can access the $node or $page variable and use this to print fields.  This is not considered a beautiful solution, but it can be quite effective.

The reason it is not so beautiful is that we like to keep code, configuration and theming separate.